# turn form_for rails html tag to regular html format

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I don't know why is anyone not asking this thing.
how would 
<%= f.label :name, "Create New" %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
this look like in regular html tag format. tnank you

Comment: Why not try your self and see what it generates ? or see documentation ? http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't usually use Rails to write plain HTML for forms. It just goes against normal convention and kills productivity. But since you asked, the easiest way would be to write the code and see what it renders. In this case it will be something like:

```
<form>
    <label for"model_name">Create New</labe>
    <input type="text" id="model_name"/>
</form>
```